# Maximization under constraints

Tags: functions, optimization

I would like to maximize the function:

$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lvert x_i-\frac{1}{N}\rvert$

under the constrains
$\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i=1$ and $0\le x_i \le 1$ $\forall i\in(1,...,N)$

I have done some test for small values of $N$ and I have the feeling that the solution is $1-\frac{1}{N}$ but I can't figure out how to solve it analytically.

Comment: Sorry, made a typo. Now it's corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the point in which the function takes the maximum value. If there are two numbers that lie on the different sides of $1/N$, i.e. $x_i<1/N<x_j$ (otherwise you can make $x_i$ a little bit smaller and $x_j$ the same little bit larger so that the function value will grow) then either $x_i=0$ or $x_j=1$. Lets assume that none of the numbers is equal to one.

Now look at all nonzero numbers. They are either all greater then $1/N$ all smaller. The latter is impossible. So all numbers are greater then $1/N$. But then the value of your function is $1-m/N$ where $m$ is the number of nonzero $x_i$s.

Comment: Whoa! Have not looked at it this way. Very clever.